# Run through sub elements of an js object and replace their properties from local store values/store their properties to local storage

Tags: javascript

So I have been working on a text game based on Colossal Cave Adventure using HTML, CSS, and JS. I was working on a save function to store all of the data into a local storage and then call it back later.

```
var rooms = {
    room1 = {
         item1 = "one"
         item2 = "two"
    }
    room2 = {
         item1 = "one"
         item2 = "two"
    }
 }
```

That is a general idea of the kind of object that I am using to store the room data. I would like to be able to save the entire object to local storage, then retreive it and replace the current object with it when the user activates a certain input.
Help?
Thank you!

Comment: Save: Convert the object to JSON with `JSON.stringify()`. Save the JSON to local storage. Restore: Retrieve the JSON from local storage, parse it with `JSON.parse()`, assign that to the variable.

Comment: Can you post your attempts so far ?

Comment: I didn't even know where to start... no attempts

Comment: @barmar could you post an example of that?

Comment: I could, but I won't. SO is not a free coding service. We'll help you fix your code, we won't write it for you. You need to do your own research.  Here's a start: https://blog.logrocket.com/storing-retrieving-javascript-objects-localstorage/